# Redraw custom NSTextField when bindings value changes?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield

I have a custom `NSTextField` sub-class with a custom `drawRect:` implementation.

The text field is part of a view inside a table cell. I programmatically bind the `fontBold` property of the text field.

The problem is that I have to recalculate a few things when the `fontBold` binding changes, but I can't figure out how to get notified when that happens.

I tried adding an observer, but that is not called. There does not seem to be a `setFontBold:(BOOL)` method that I could overwrite in `NSTextField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

There really is no `fontBold` property. I think what happens under the hood is that the binding is transformed by a value transformer into an `NSFont` object and what actually changes is the `font` attribute of `NSTextField` (I confirmed that `setFont:` is called when the `fontBold` binding changes). Phew, 4 hours of my life gone.